# ClickListener for Slide Menu items error FATAL Exception Main

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I am using the drawable menu.

I have this code:

```
public class KeretaApiFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_kereta_api);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button pilihka = (Button) getView().findViewById(id.btnpilihdgnka);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kereta_api, container, false);

    pilihka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            Intent i = new Intent(KeretaApiFragment.this.getActivity(), PilihDenganKA.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

and this error
from Logcat:

```
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.example.taapps.KeretaApiFragment.onCreateView(KeretaApiFragment.java:25)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-07 19:00:43.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me.

Comment: You have the exact location of NPE in the log. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kereta_api, container, false);

    Button pilihka = (Button) rootView.findViewById(id.btnpilihdgnka);

    pilihka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PilihDenganKA.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` in `onCreateView()` returns `null` - you haven't yet returned anything to the framework. Use the `rootView` you inflate instead.

`setContentView()` and `super.onCreate()` seem to be some copy-paste artifacts from an activity - you should not need them in a fragment like this.